# remove an object from different queues without iterating them or using hard-code

Tags: java, algorithm

In my code, I am using 28800 different queues for some reasons. And these queues can contain same object with different order at same time. For example

```
LinkedList<Object> queue1 = new LinkedList<Object>();
Vector<Object> queue2 = new Vector<Object>();
ArrayList<Object> queue3 = new ArrayList<Object>();
...

Object a = new Object();
Object b = new Object();
Object c = new Object();
queue1.add(a);
queue1.add(b);
queue1.add(c);
queue2.add(b);
queue2.add(c);
queue3.add(c);
```

Exactly what I need is that, I want to remove an object from all of these 28800 queues.

How can I remove an object from all queues without iterating them or hard-coding 28800 lines like `queueX.remove(myObject);`

Actually I am looking for smarter way, Is it possible?

Also I tried set null the object which I want to deallocate but all of these queue types (arraylist, linkedlist, vector etc) still contains that object as null state.

P.S: I tried it in java but language can be c or c#, it doesn't matter actually. So I am flexible about queue types like arraylist, vector etc.

Comment: Depends on the "remove" you want. You could invalidate the instance with a boolean, if every Queue share the sane reference. So this will stay in the Queue but could be skipped during the reading of those queues. But this will need to be clean at some point (a filter on every invalidated instance)

Comment: I mean that real remove meaning. Because I want to reduce size of queues when I remove it. Using flag is increase heap size and when I want to pop an object from queue I need lookup up to it's flag. It is unwanted cost :( @AxelH

Comment: Maybe you can keep track on all locations? Or use weak references - then on every object access you check wether its still valid.

Comment: Put all the queues into a container and a single `foreach` loop (or equivalent) on that container will process all the queues.

Comment: If you need to delete this instance in each Queues `without iterating them or hard-coding 28800 `. I doubt there is an answer to that without having a reference in the other way (Object know Queue) but this will be awful.

Comment: Checking valid or using flag is a way but adds a control cost for every delete event, right?. @Matthias

Comment: I doubt too, so I asked in here :) @AxelH

Comment: You either have a cost by iterating on 28k Queue on each remove, or you have a cost of an `if(valid)` on each reading. Depending on the needs, both are valid. I would prefer to have a thread removing the invalid line from times to times (to keep the best of both ;) )

Comment: Can you give us more details? maybe a simple way exist but we cannot find because we don't have enough details (28800 queue might be ok, but i don't think you have 28800 variables, also why so much queues?

Answer (score 2):

The smarter way is that your Object broadcast a "deleteMe" event, then all the Queues would listen to that event and react accordingly by removing that Object from themselves. For this to work you would first have to have some kind of event registration and event dispatching mechanism implemented.

Comment: A simple Observer could do it then. But you still need to store your queues somewhere to respond to those events.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of storing object references you could store WeakReference references. WeakReferences are part of Java SDK. You would

- Maintain a List (A) that stores references to your real objects
- Maintain in your many queues weak references to your real objects
- When you want to delete a object you delete it in List A. Then the object should be weakly reachable
- When you acces an object via the WeakReferences you just check "weakReference.get() == null" to see wether or not the object is still valid?

The sample code would look like this:

```
  LinkedList<Object> real_objects = new LinkedList<Object>();
  LinkedList<WeakReference<Object>> queue1 = new LinkedList<WeakReference<Object>>();
  Vector<WeakReference<Object> queue2 = new Vector<WeakReference<Object>>();
  ArrayList<WeakReference<Object>> queue3 = new ArrayList<WeakReference<Object>>();

  Object a = new Object();
  Object b = new Object();
  Object c = new Object();

  real_objects.add(a);
  real_objects.add(b);
  real_objects.add(c);

  queue1.add(new WeakReference<Object>(a));
  queue1.add(new WeakReference<Object>(b));
  queue1.add(new WeakReference<Object>(c));

  queue2.add(new WeakReference<Object>(a));
  queue2.add(new WeakReference<Object>(c));

  queue3.add(new WeakReference<Object>(a));
```

Now if you realize that Object a is no longer needed you would first remove it from the real_objects List:

```
  real_objects.remove(a);
  a = NULL;
```

Now Object a is weakly reachable and during the next iteration of the Garbage Collector it will be marked as finalizable.
The WeakReferences to a no longer reference a, but when they are queried for their Object (via get()) return null.

So if you now do start your queue processing with for example:

```
 WeakReference<Object> weakRef = queue1.get(0); // in this example this would be a weak referenc to Object a

 if (weakRef.get() == null) {
    // the underlying "real" object was already deleted...
    queue1.remove(weakRef);
 } {
    // the underlying "real" object was not deleted and can be processed
    Object y = weakRef.get();

    // now y can be processed...
 }
```

In this solution it is important to differ between Objects, References and Weak References. There is some reading available on the oracle website:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/WeakReference.html
- https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ref/package-summary.html#reachability

Comment: Didn't knew there were an existing class for this, a simple generic wrapper. The WeakReference would stay but the referenced instance would be cleaned by the garbage collector. So this is better then mine !

Comment: How can remove a weakReference form all queues? Can you add that to your sample code, please. @Matthias

Comment: You don't! Whenever you have to access an object from "the queues" you get a WeakReference. Youu check it's validity (weakRef.get() == null). When the real object is no longer valid get() returns null. In this case you can delete it and proceed with next "object". You would no longer bulk proces the queues, but on each object access you have to do some more work...

Comment: My code is like that queue1.add(new WeakReference<Object>(a)); then a = null; then System.out.println("item1: "  + queue1.get(0));. and it returns me not null, it returns java.lang.ref.WeakReference@4537ef34. But I set it null already. Why get() function did not return null? @Matthias

Comment: Thank you @Matthias. One last thing, how can I get top element which it's weakreference is not null without iterating queue?

Comment: That's the real point which I want to skip. In your way too, I must check "is current top item's weakref null" on O(N/2) times complexity. this is what I want to escape in the code :) @Matthias So there is no difference between using flags or using weak ref, except using extra memory for flags.

Answer (score 0):

So, my idea would be to use a simple flag to invalidate the instance. Using this, you could invalidate every instance in one call (if you already have the instance).

```
public class MyObject {

    boolean valid = true;

    void invalid(){ valid = false; }
    boolean isValid(){ return valid; }
}
```

Here is a simple snippet to use this:

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args){
        List<MyObject> list = new ArrayList<MyObject>();

        list.add(new MyObject());
        list.add(new MyObject());
        list.add(new MyObject());
        list.add(new MyObject());
        list.add(new MyObject());

        list.get(2).invalid();
        list.get(0).invalid();

        int count=0;
        for(MyObject o : list){
            if(o.isValid()){
                count++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Valid count : " + count);
    }
}
```

Then, too clean the `Queues` from time to time, I would use a `Thread` that would remove every invalidate instance from time to time. The frequency of this cleaning depends on the needs of course.

Comment: good effort. but there is sth like that, these queues are alive, I mean in every second code push items to queue or/and pull items from them. So if I create thread for remove job. It could make some mistakes. Also if I use lock or sync with thread, it reduces code performance because of waiting thread finishes its job.